# Lazarus отладка кода в библиотечных классах

Tags: отладка, lazarus, gdb

По непонятной причине отладка в библиотечном коде теперь невозможна. При пошагофой отладке, дебагер останавливается на вызове и перепрыгивыет его, хотя нажимается F7. Так же в стандартной библиотеке, в строках отлаживаемого кода нет знака, что код скомпилирован.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как можно это исправить?

По аналогии с Delphi это доллжна быть опция компилятора "Use debug DCU's", но в Lazarus такого не нашел.

Comment: Смотрю на метку gdb, которую вы добавили. Вы правда используете https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger для отладки Lazarus кода?

Comment: Под Linux я знаю только  эту возможность.

Comment: @svd71 Логично предположить, что библиотека собрана без опций отладки , поэтому компилятор,  обходит эти функции.